# What are the disadvantages of using code-behind to handle child windows in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

Suppose it's required to create a child window and handle the result from some viewmodel.

For this we could use the code behind.

Example:

```
// Code Behind
class SampleView : ISampleView
{
  public void CreateChildWindow(params string [] args)
  {
      var childWIndow = ChildViewFactory.Create(args);
      childWindow.Closed += 
      () =>  {
                if(childWindow.Result)
                {
                    this.ViewModel.DoSomething();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.ViewModel.DoSomethingElse();
                }
             };
      childWindow.Show();
  }
}

// ViewModel
class SampleViewModel
{
     private void OnSomeCommandHandler()
     {
         ((ISampleView)this.View).CreateChildWindow(new []{""});
     }

     public void DoSomething()
     {

     }

     public void DoSomethingElse()
     {

     }
}
```

I haven't seen this approach anywhere, however it seems to be rather logical.

Since that I was wondering - what are the possible disadvantages using this pattern?

Comment: depends on what your `childWindow.Result` is. Right now the if check of `Result` property is not testable being in the View. If it's in the VM and you use a messenger/event-aggregator pattern, you can keep the UI-logic testable and also mock them comfortably in unit-tests without loosing code-coverage in tests. Opening /closing windows from code-behind is perfectly valid, it's very easy to overdo it and shoot ourselves in the foot, so some caution can never be too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked a rather subjective question here. Hardcore MVVM developers *might* say that you should *never* use the code behind files, whilst others may say that this is completely fine.

The main reason for the separation of code from views is to allow *all* of the view model code to be easily tested with mock data access classes. Some people will tell you that this separation also allows us to swap out different views of the same content, but I have never needed to do this.

I'm sure that you'll find people that say that you should *never* open a view from the view model - that the view model should not know anything about the views. These people would use some kind of service layer to launch views (indirectly) from the view models. Others will tell you that launching child views from parent view code behind is exactly what you should do.

At the end of the day, this really is a personal decision about what suits you and the application that you are developing. As we generally test view models rather than views (yes, I am aware of automated UI testing in WPF), I'd say the only reason for not using the view code behind is because that code won't be tested (at least in the normal way along with the view model code).

However, do we ever really need to test the simple code that launches a child window? In my opinion, we don't... Microsoft have already tested that for us. So to answer your question, I'd say that the disadvantage of using code behind to launch child windows will depend on your personal situation, but it is unlikely to be a serious disadvantage, if any.

Comment: `Hardcore MVVM developers might say that you should never use the code behind files` Those are the developers that do not understand MVVM

Comment: Maybe 'hardcore' was not the best way to describe them, but yes... they're the ones that I was talking about. :)